# Using an array for functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm trying to create a program that uses an array of functions to cycle through the order of execution. I've included the program below, can somebody please suggest what i have done wrong.I have created a set of traffic lights on HTML and im trying to write some javascript that will change which light is displayed when a button is clicked. I've created an array of functions that determines the order i want the lights to appear in. I've also written the functions that will display each light. I'm new to javascript, any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Task three</title>
    <link href="Task 3-CSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Task3-Java.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="control_panel">
    <button onclick="change_light">Change Light</button>
</div>

<div id="traffic_light">
    <div id="red_light" class="light"></div>
    <div id="amber_light" class="light"></div>
    <div id="green_light" class="light"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

var light_array=[red,red_amber,green,amber];
var light_index = 0;

function no_light(){
    document.getElementById('red_light').style.backgroundColor = "black";
    document.getElementById('amber_light').style.backgroundColor = "black";
    document.getElementById('green_light').style.backgroundColor = "black";
}

function red(){
    no_light();
    document.getElementById('red_light').style.backgroundColor="red";
}

function red_amber(){
    no_light();
    document.getElementById('red_light').style.backgroundColor="red";
    document.getElementById('amber_light').style.backgroundColor="orange";
}

function green(){
    no_light();
    document.getElementById('green_light').style.backgroundColor="green";
}

function amber(){
    no_light();
    document.getElementById('amber_light').style.backgroundColor="orange";
}

function change_light(){
    light_array[light_index](red,red_amber,green,amber);
    light_index++;
    if (light_index > 3){light_index = 0;}

}
change_light();
```

Comment: Can you tell us what problem you are having? Do you get an error?

Comment: You should change your tag sas this doesn't concern Java. Java and Javascript are completely different.

Comment: I always wonder why incomplete questions that are not that complex get up voted within seconds of being posted.

Comment: I suggest you add the relevant HTML and make it a Stack Snippet, so we can test your code right here in your question - check the chapter about [mcve]. Also, you forgot to actually explain *how* your code does not work or not do what you expect.

Comment: You *probably* want: `var light_array=[red,red_amber,green,amber]`  Though it's not really clear to me how you're even *using* this array.

Comment: I think your problem is not calling the change_light() method within the .js file. Just write the line change_light(); below the function and it should work as expected, if that is what you are looking for. Combine this with @TJ Croweder's answer.

Comment: @David: It's used near the bottom of the code.

Comment: I upvoted it, may I? :) For me it's quite complete and clear what the problem OP has.

Comment: @dfsq The OP hasn't explained what problem he's having or if he's even getting an error. In order for anyone to be helpful, they must read through the code, not having a clue as to what they are looking for. In this case, the error was at the beginning, but that doesn't make this a good question. Please don't reward poor questions as it will simply encourage poor questions in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to move all the `document.getElementById()` to variable declarations.

In the html instead of doing `onclick="change_light"` you should do `onclick="change_light()"`

In one line you can handle the light_index variable with `light_index = (light_index >= 3) ? 0 : ++light_index;`

The rest of the answers has well covered all the other points.

Working example:

```js
var light_array = [red, red_amber, green, amber],
  light_index = 0,
  red_light_elem = document.getElementById('red_light'),
  amber_light_elem = document.getElementById('amber_light'),
  green_light_elem = document.getElementById('green_light');

function no_light() {
  red_light_elem.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  amber_light_elem.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  green_light_elem.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
}

function red() {
  no_light();
  red_light_elem.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}

function red_amber() {
  no_light();
  red_light_elem.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  amber_light_elem.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
}

function green() {
  no_light();
  green_light_elem.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
}

function amber() {
  no_light();
  amber_light_elem.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
}

function change_light() {
  light_array[light_index]();
  light_index = (light_index >= 3) ? 0 : ++light_index;
}
```

```html
<div id="control_panel">
    <button onclick="change_light()">Change Light</button>
</div>

<div id="traffic_light">
    <div id="red_light" class="light">red</div>
    <div id="amber_light" class="light">amber</div>
    <div id="green_light" class="light">green</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're **calling** the functions and storing the result in the array. You should just be referring to them (without `()`):

```
var light_array=[red,red_amber,green,amber];
```

Then call them when you want to call them (e.g., in `change_light`):

```
light_array[light_index]();
// ---------------------^
```

---

BTW, the code updating `light_index` is incorrect, you should be incrementing **before** the `if`:

```
function change_light(){
    light_array[light_index]();
    light_index++;                         // <== Moved this up
    if (light_index > 3){light_index = 0;}
}
```

...but there's a handy trick for that which combines it into one expression:

```
function change_light(){
    light_array[light_index]();
    light_index = (light_index + 1) % light_array.length;
}
```

That handles wrap-around for you. Also note how I used `light_array.length` rather than a hardcoded number, so that if you add/remove entries in the array, the code still works.

Comment: @YosvelQuintero: Thanks for letting me know, I forgot the parens. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change this line

```
var light_array=[red(),red_amber(),green(),amber()];
```

for this one

```
var light_array=[red,red_amber,green,amber];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have three problems (if the rest is working)

1. using the result instead of function reference

   ```
   var light_array = [red, red_amber, green, amber];
   ```
2. missing call of the functions

   ```
   light_array[light_index]();
   //                      ^^
   ```

   You stored a reference to the function in `light_array`. To [call a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Calling_functions), you need to invoke it with parenthesis.
3. use increment before checking

   ```
   function change_light() {
       light_array[light_index](); // call function
       light_index++;              // increment counter
       if (light_index > 3) {      // check counter
           light_index = 0;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the response but can you explain part 2 please?

Comment: I've made a few change

Comment: changes* but i'm not sure how to call the function

Comment: just use the line `light_array[light_index]();` without any parameters. it works with too, but it makes no sense.